# IDEA. Symbols not showing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, character-encoding, symbols

Help please. I don't understand how fix that. In the console, for different symbols, it constantly issues "`?`" instead of symbols.
[image]
I'm trying write `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8`, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into two files `idea64.exe.vmoptions`, along the way `IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1\bin`, and `AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1`, `"UTF8"` is set everywhere in the IDEA settings.

[image]
Nothing helps, I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: What JDK do you use to run your project?

Comment: JDK 18, last version on off site

Comment: Looks like known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006/Running-the-Java-project-by-using-the-JDK-18-prints-the-garbled-

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you very much, I looked through a lot of topics, tried to find a solution for 3 days, nothing helped, but it turned out because of jdk 18, installed version 17, everything worked, very grateful.

Comment: You can leave lines like "Help please.", "I don't understand how fix that.", "Nothing helps, I don't know ....", etc. out, as they don't add any value in the actual question.